# Foreach and enumerable

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

Why we can iterate item ex

```
mList.ForEach((item) 
{
    item.xyz ....
}
```

and for a simple array we need to force foreach loop?

```
foreach(int i in arr)
    i.xyz
```

or use delegate type ?

```
Action<int> action = new Action<int>(myfunc);
Array.ForEach(intArray, action);
```

What is the differemce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language defines `foreach` as an operation of `IEnumerable`. Therefore, everything which implements `IEnumerable` is iteratable. However, not all `IEnumerable`s 'make sense' when using a `ForEach` block.

Take this for example:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyObject> GetObjects()
{
    var i = 0;
    while(i < 30)
        yield return new MyObject { Name = "Object " + i++ };
}
```

And then you do something like this:

```
var objects = GetObjects();
objects.ForEach(o => o.Name = "Rob");
foreach (var obj in objects)
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
```

***IF*** that compiled, it would print out `Object 0` to `Object 29` - NOT `Rob` 30 times.

The reason for this is that the iterator is reset *each time* you iterate the enumerable. It makes sense for `ForEach` on a list, as the enumerable has been materialized, and objects are not re-created every time you iterate it.

In order to make `ForEach` work on an enumerable, you'd need to materialize the collection as well (such as putting it into a list), but even *that* is not always possible, as you can have an enumerable with no defined end:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyObject> GetObjects()
{
    while(true)
        yield return new MyObject { Name = "Object " };
}
```

It *also* makes sense to have `ForEach` on `Array` - but for reasons I'm unaware of, it was defined as `Array.ForEach(arr)` rather than `arr.ForEach()`

Moral of the story is, if you think you need a `ForEach` block, you probably want to materialize the enumerable first, usually to a `List<T>` or an array (`T[]`).

Answer (score 4):

The first syntax is not correct. It should be like this:

```
mList.ForEach(item => 
{
    // item.xyz
});
```

The `ForEach` is a method of `List<T>` that enables you for each item in a list to call an `Action<T>`.

On the other hand the `foreach`

> statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each element in
>   an array or an object collection that implements the
>   System.Collections.IEnumerable or
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable interface.

That being said, `ForEach` can be called only on lists and `foreach` can be called on any object that implements either `IEnumerable` or IEnumerable. That's the big difference here.

Regarding the delegate type,  there isn't any difference. Actually, lambda expressions `item=>{ item.xyz = ...}` are a shorthand for delegates.

Comment: of course the sintax is with =>. But the question is why if I have int[] intArray = new int[] {2, 3, 4}; i can't iterate with .ForEach instead forech( bla bla )

Comment: Because `ForEach` is a method of `List` or `List<T>`, while `intArray` is an array of int.